# Know the return value of a disabled select

Tags: javascript, select

I want to check if a dropdown is diasbled.
If it is i have further actions to do.
according to me a disabled dropdown returns a value -1 .
Can any one tell me any other way to do it in javascript.

Following is my code :

```
         if(form["view.modeEnabled"].value == "true"){


             if((form.outFlag.checked) && ((form.outMode.value == -1) || (form.outMode.value == 0))){
                 invalidOut = true;
              }

             if((form.outFlag.checked) && ((form.outMode.value == 1))){
                if(form.outModele.value == -1 || form.outModele.value == 0){
                    invalidOut = true;
                }
              }

              if((form.outFlag.checked) && ((form.outMode.value == 2))){
                if(form.outModeleRes.value == -1 || form.outModeleRes.value == 0){
                    invalidOut = true;
                }
              }

              if((form.outFlag.checked) && ((form.outMode.value == 3))){
                if(form.outModeleRes.value == -1 || form.outModeleRes.value == 0 || form.outModele.value == -1 || form.outModele.value == 0 ){
                    invalidOut = true;
                }
              }

               if((form.inFlag.checked) && ((form.inMode.value == -1)|| (form.inMode.value == 0))){
                invalidIn = true;
              }

              if((form.inFlag.checked) && ((form.inMode.value == 1))){
                if(form.inModele.value == -1 || form.inModele.value == 0){
                    invalidOut = true;
                }
              }

              if((form.inFlag.checked) && ((form.inMode.value == 2))){
                if(form.inModeleRes.value == -1 || form.inModeleRes.value == 0){
                    invalidOut = true;
                }
              }

              if((form.inFlag.checked) && ((form.inMode.value == 3))){
                if(form.inModeleRes.value == -1 || form.inModeleRes.value == 0 || form.inModele.value == -1 || form.inModele.value == 0 ){
                    invalidOut = true;
                }
              }

              if((invalidOut == false) && (invalidIn == false)){
                  submitForm(form)  ;
              }else{
                // alert('La sélection du mode est obligatoire pour HO IN / OUT création');
                window.message="La sélection du mode est obligatoire pour HO IN / OUT création";
                OuvrirFenetreModal('popupErrorCreate.jsp','popup','top=300,left=350,directories=no,width=300,height=80,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no');
              }
         }else{
                submitForm(form)    ;
          }
```

Comment: Is your question simply how to determine if a select is disabled?

Comment: that would also do...

Answer (score 0):

A disabled select does not return `-1` as its value, it returns the selected option's value.  If you want to determine if a select is disabled, simply use the `disabled` property.  This is a boolean indicating if the select is disabled.

```
if(mySelect.disabled){
    // do something here in the event that it is disabled
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tx8PY/